# Bash Script repetitive codes

Tags: bash, shell

I have one bash script. MongoDB queries are working, but these script should work both without authenticating and with authenticate. So it will run on different MongoDBs. There are a lot of code duplication. What are your suggestions for this? Or this is the best way ?

Example:

```
mongo $MONGODB_IP/db1 --quiet --host $MONGO_IP --username $MONGO_USER --password $MONGO_PASS --eval 'queries'
mongo $MONGODB_IP/db1 --quiet --eval 'queries'
```

Comment: Your script appears to do both right now; what's your question looking for? (Noting that "suggestions and "best way" lead off-topic to opinion-based answers)

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I'm just looking at how I can make it shorter.

Comment: Are you space constrained in some way? Sometimes being explicit is clearer to future maintainers (such as yourself) and worth the expense of some number of bytes. Separately, I'd suggest an [edit] to your question to clarify your intention.

Comment: You can easily setup a variable with the optional additional parameters, and leave it empty when they're not needed. These those two lines could be factored into just one, with that variable's value changing between the two calls.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I think it's not about space, but about code maintainability: if the two sets of calls are all identical, except for the credentials options, the code would be clearer and easier to maintain if each call was defined just once.

Comment: FYI, both the approaches given in the answer currently proposed are ones described in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of repeating common arguments, you could pass specific arguments to a function, and keep the common arguments within the function:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

run_mongo() {
  mongo "$MONGODB_IP/db1" "$@" --quiet --eval 'queries'
}

#mongo "$MONGODB_IP/db1" --quiet --host "$MONGO_IP" --username "$MONGO_USER" --password "$MONGO_PASS" --eval 'queries'
run_mongo --host "$MONGO_IP" --username "$MONGO_USER" --password "$MONGO_PASS"
#mongo "$MONGODB_IP/db1" --quiet --eval 'queries'
run_mongo
```

Or you could store common arguments in an array:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mongo_common_args=(
  "$MONGODB_IP/db1" --quiet --eval 'queries'
)

#mongo "$MONGODB_IP/db1" --quiet --host "$MONGO_IP" --username "$MONGO_USER" --password "$MONGO_PASS" --eval 'queries'
mongo --host "$MONGO_IP" --username "$MONGO_USER" --password "$MONGO_PASS" "${mongo_common_args[@]}"
#mongo "$MONGODB_IP/db1" --quiet --eval 'queries'
mongo "${mongo_common_args[@]}"
```